# In-place creation and push to a vector of const references

Tags: c++

The code I am trying to unit-test has a structure similar to the one below, where there is a vector of const references to a custom struct:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    std::vector<int> v;
};

typedef std::reference_wrapper<const MyStruct> ConstStructReference;
typedef std::vector<ConstStructReference> MyStructs;

int main() {
    MyStruct my_struct{.x = 1, .v={2,3}};
    MyStructs my_structs;
    mystructs.push_back(my_struct);
    // mystructs.push_back(MyStruct{.x = 1, .v={2,3}}); // Error error: use of deleted function ‘std::reference_wrapper<_Tp>::reference_wrapper(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = const MyStruct]’
    return 0;
}
```

The code of my tests would be much simpler if I could use some kind of in-place creation of MyStruct and pushing into `mystructs`, but I keep getting errors like `error: use of deleted function ‘std::reference_wrapper<_Tp>::reference_wrapper(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = const MyStruct]’`. I tried different things, but I didn't manage to have everything in one line.

Is there any way to get a line similar to `mystructs.push_back(MyStruct{.x = 1, .v={2,3}});` or is simply not possible?

Thanks!

Comment: No, because that would be pushing in a reference to a temporary, which makes no sense. References need to refer to something that outlives them. Why do you _think_ you need to do that? This is probably an X/Y question.

Comment: Given the trivial nature of `std::reference_wrapper`, attempting to use `emplace`, or move semantics is not going to accomplish anything.

Comment: What part of that code is test code and which part is non-test code? This seems a lot like an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I do not think I need that. I just wanted to decrease the number of lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried different things, but I didn't manage to have everything in one line.

Here is a working solution:

```
MyStruct my_struct{.x = 1, .v={2,3}}; MyStructs my_structs{my_struct};
```

The problem with your attempt is that the references are for referring to an object stored elsewhere. That is why a reference wrapper constructor doesn't accept rvalue arguments. If you were to pass a temporary object like you attempted, the wrapped reference would be invalid as soon as it has been created (after the full expression).

Comment: While the paragraph is helpful and validates my understanding, the "working solution" is not really a solution. Please remove that part and I will accept the answer.

Comment: @Javi It's on a single line. It's a solution to the problem that you stated.

Comment: Title says: "In-place creation and push". The final question says "any way to get a line similar to `mystructs.push_back(MyStruct{.x = 1, .v={2,3}});`". I do not think it solves for what I am asking.

Comment: @Javi Technically, `MyStructs my_structs{my_struct}` does create the reference wrapper "inline". Why do you think the solution isn't similar?